# How to open .srt file in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, subtitle, srt

I have an APP to play video and `.srt` subtitle.

The problem is that I don't know how to open the `.srt` subtitle file.

I have tried:

```
NSString *content=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding error:nil];
```

in which case, the string turns out to be messy code.

And I tried:

```
NSString *content=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Now, the string turns out to be null.

I also tried read as `NSData` from file first, and make `NSString` from `NSData`, but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text encoding for `.srt` subtitle files is not well defined. If decoding the text as UTF-8 fails, try ISO 8859-1 (`NSISOLatin1StringEncoding`) as a fallback.

Comment: It works!! Very thank you. One problem, the English subtitles and timeline show well, but the Chinese subtitles are still messy code

Comment: The Chinese subtitles may be in yet another encoding. If they aren't UTF-8, try Big5 or GBK? Ultimately it's kind of a guessing game.

Comment: Yes, I tried `kCFStringEncodingGBK_95` , it works. Thank you!

Comment: hey, can you tell me how to read and play this .str file?? i searched a lot, but could not find any help. Thanx in advance..